# Windows 10 boot messed up, repairing without losing dual-boot Linux?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

My PC has Ubuntu and Windows 10 LTSC dual boot, installed on an SSD.

I've restarted my PC and switch to Windows and noticed it won't boot, it keeps going into automatic repair. It gives something like "check SrtTrail.txt" and I tried a few solutions on the internet but they weren't helpful. I ran chkdsk, ntfsfix, fsck but no luck.

Then I decided, well, disk is healthy, I can get my data out of it. Let's reinstall Windows. Afaik when you plug an installation USB you get an option to repair Windows.

But I was worried that repair will mess my Ubuntu partition. I know it will override boot manager, I can install it again, but I'm worried about the Ubuntu installation itself.

Would the Windows repair thing touch my Ubuntu partition? If "maybe" or yes, when reinstalling it, I can choose a partition and it will just install it there, right?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I just can't be sure what Windows will do.

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% sure answer where software is concerned.

The 99% answer is that repairing Windows may only destroy the dual-boot but
will not touch the Ubuntu partition, which will only happen if you ask the installation
to format the whole disk.

BUT I will suggest taking backups of your data before starting such serious operations.
Do NOT assume "disk is healthy, I can get my data out of it".

I suggest in addition, to take a backup of the entire hard disk using a third-party
product such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html).